# Run a remote firefox session locally

Tags: firefox, remote

I'm trying to run a remote firefox session on my vps, to try to download some large files to the server.

I've installed firefox from the apt repo remotely, and I also have firefox installed on my Ubuntu based PC.

After doing:

```
$ssh -X root@myip
root@myip's password: 
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-308.8.2.el5.028stab101.1 x86_64)
```

I type the following on the server:

```
$firefox -no-remote
(firefox:6026): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Error: no display specified
```

So I see two errors: "X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0" and "Error: no display specified". I'm doing something wrong, and would like to find out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my issues.

```
Error: "X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0"
```

and

```
"Error: no display specified"
```

Solution:

Add the following to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the client:

```
ForwardX11 yes
```

On the remote, install the following package: xauth

```
apt-get install xauth
```

Comment: It it is solved, then mark the answer solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `elinks` as a command line browser, or `wget` to download.
+ use `screen` to disconnect from the terminal but keep it running on the server.

Comment: Indeed elinks was the first I tried. But it doesnt work on most java pages, even with spidermonkey.

Comment: Yes, if you wan't to use java, you need a gui browser.